# Share JS varible once incremented on a timer

Tags: javascript, html

The following is the function I’m trying out:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<code>
var xl = 0;
window.onload = setInterval(plusone, 1000);
function plusone(){
xl++; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xl;
}
if (xl == 0){
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "zero";
}
else if (xl == 5){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "5";
}
else if (xl == 7){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
}
else if (xl == 20){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
}
else if (xl == 19){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "na";
}
</code>
```

My aim is to change a `<p>` block depending on what the incremented time is.

The issue here is that the `if` statements don’t work with the incremented `xl`.

Comment: Why not move all if-else ifs inside PlusOne? Those ifs need to also be reevaluatwed on a timer

Comment: Why is all of your JavaScript in a `<code>` element?!

Comment: `window.onload = setInterval(plusone, 1000);` — It doesn't make sense to assign the return value of `setInterval` (which is a number representing the interval) to `onload` (which must be a function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed your condition statements outside the function you call on load. Also better use `switch-case` statement for that kind of job:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<code>
    var xl = 0;
    // Anonymous function
    window.onload = function() {
               setInterval(plusone, 1000);
    }

    function plusone(){
        xl++; 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xl;

        switch(xl) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "zero";
                break;
            case 5:
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "5";
                break;
            case 7: 
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
                break;
            case 20:
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
                break;
            case 19:
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
                break;
            default
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "na";
        }
    }


</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are having some problems with brackets you miss placed them and also you should use script tag not code tag.
here is the working code
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wbo4vnt/1/)

```
     <p id="demo"></p>
     <p id="demo2"></p>
     <script>
     var xl = 0;
     window.onload = setInterval(plusone, 1000);
     function plusone(){
     xl++;

     if (xl == 0){
       document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "zero";
     }
     else if (xl == 5){
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "5";
     }
     else if (xl == 7){
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
     }
     else if (xl == 20){
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
     }
     else if (xl == 19){
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
     }
     else
     {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "na";
     }
     }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code only runs when something causes it to run.

The if statements run when the document first loads because they are inline in the script.

The interval you have running then repeatedly runs the `plusone` function which changes the value of  `xl` but **you never rerun the code with the if statements**.

You should put that in a function and call it whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

As they said in comment this is wrong :

```
window.onload = setInterval(plusone, 1000);
```

the window.onload is not used there because it is the return value of setInterval and not the function that is set, instead use anonymous functions like this :

```
window.onload = function() { setInterval(plusone, 1000);}
```

Then your if statement is only executed once its because its not part of plusOne method (check your brackets) so once the parser go through your main it will just be executed once.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script> 
var xl = 0;
// Proper use of anonymous function for window.onload
window.onload = function() { 
       setInterval(plusone, 1000);
}
function plusone(){
    xl++;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xl;

    if (xl == 0){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "zero";
    }
    else if (xl == 5){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "5";
    }
    else if (xl == 7){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
    }
    else if (xl == 20){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
    }
    else if (xl == 19){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "na";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the reply.

I got the following working now as forgotten to refreash the code

```
<script>
var xl = 0;

window.onload = setInterval(plusone, 1000);
window.onload = setInterval(plustwo, 1000);


function plusone(){
xl++;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xl;
}

function plustwo(){

if (xl == 0){
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "zero";
}
else if (xl == 2){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "5";
}
else if (xl == 3){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
}
else if (xl == 4){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;

} 
else if (xl == 5){
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xl;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "na";
}
}
</script>
```